# Is there any way to detect if android screen content is changing?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

Suppose that I have an android application which always runs at background. What the app does is listening for any changes on android's screen and then take a note to database. (This is a useful legal feature of the app that I am developing). So, Is there any way to listen for the changes of android's screen?

UPDATE1: I want to detect the change of screen content, Not just the orientation.

Update2: I found an application [(Droid VNC)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5vbmFpcHMudm5jIl0.) did this very good. Anyone know what technology VNC use there?
Thanks,

Nguyen Minh Binh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are definitely talking about screen content not orientation if yes then you have to sense the framebuffer of device for that you need rooted device

Comment: Yes, you right. Could you give me a URL of a tutorial/ example?

Comment: Thanks again for the keyword "framebuffer" :)

Comment: I don't have detailed idea of framebuffer someone else can help you in this

Answer (score 0):

[onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) may help you

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   //YOUR STUFF HERE
}
```

Comment: That is for an `Activity` so can not be used in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Service` which uses the `SensorManager` to detect orientation changes.